# Is it unhealthy to eat the oil in the food?

Tags: diet, food-safety

I likes to eat the oil which is in the food. But, I have listened we should not eat that oil. I want to ask that is this oil unhealthy and creates problem in the body ?

Comment: Please, better specify which oil